# How to integrate pushpaymentViewcontroller for stripe in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

This question is for documenting proper steps that are needed to integrate `pushPaymentMethodsViewController()` in stripe for Ios.

There is a [medicore](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/custom) documentation provided by stripe, with little to no support

For eg.,As per the documentation it says to implement

```
self.paymentCont.pushPaymentMethodsViewController()
```

once implemented in onClick button action, it sends out an error saying

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'hostViewController must not be nil on STPPaymentContext when calling pushPaymentMethodsViewController on it. Next time, set the hostViewController property first!'`

As per the docs it says to implement

```
 let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyKeyProvider().shared())
```

So what does `customerContext` do ?

Any proper support to assist the above mentioned task would be greatly appreciated.